# Are $\alpha, \beta$ of Beta distribution positive integer inn Thompson Sampling

Tags: beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, conjugate-prior, multiarmed-bandit

In [wikipedia on beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), they say that domain of hyperparameter $\alpha, \beta$ are positive real numbers.

[image: domain of beta distribution]

However, according to my reasons, the domain of $\alpha, \beta$ should be limited to positive integers in context of [Thompson Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling), where Beta distribution is used as conjugate prior of Bernoulli distribution, such that [interpretation of hyperparameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution)  can be $\alpha$ successes and $\beta$ failures.

Is my understanding right? or it doesn't matter to set $\alpha, \beta$ as continuous variables ?
If my reasoning is correct, then how can I *prove* (e.g. mathematically) it?

Comment: There's no mathematical way to demonstrate that you cannot use a prior with non-integral parameters (because this is not a mathematical question) and there are many statistical reasons why you *would* want to use such a prior.

Comment: @whuber can you give me some example of *many statistical reasons* to use non-integral parameters?

Comment: One well-known example is the [Jeffreys prior for a Bernoulli variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#Bernoulli_trial) where $\alpha=\beta=1/2.$ More generally, the choice of prior represents a degree of belief and there is no reason whatsoever to suppose that one person's belief is correctly represented only by integral parameters.